# Check if database credentials are valid?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a small self-hosted app which requires database usage. I'd like to validate that the user inputted database credentials are valid, before they're actually saved. What could I do to check whether or not a connection is valid, would it be as simple as?

```
$conn = mysql_connect($db_name, $db_user, $db_pass); mysql_select_db($db_name);

if($conn) {
    mysql_close($conn);
    // Do stuff if connection is valid
} else {
    mysql_close($conn);
    // Do stuff if connection is invalid
    }
```

Would I even need to close the connection if it's invalid? (Within the `else{}` statement. I took a look at `mysql_ping()` but it doesn't really seem to be what I need.

Comment: every time your db is going to be mysql only or it can change? bcz then i dont think it will work.

Comment: What? - If you're asking whether or not the databases used will be MySQL all the time, yes. I wouldn't call the function `mysql_connect()` to connect to another database type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the credentials are invalid, no need to close the connection as it won't be open in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was thinking. Aside from that, is my code fine? (Should have really asked, does `mysql_connect()` return `TRUE`).

Comment: `mysql_connect()` returns a MySQL link identifier on success, which == true.

Answer (score 0):

also frequently used is 'die' which allows you to print a message before stopping execution of the script:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($db_name, $db_user, $db_pass) or die('the error message');
```

or for debugging purposes the following is frequently used:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($db_name, $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
```

which will print the mysql error such as a warning about wrong credentials

Comment: Yeah, I usually use `die()` when de-bugging, but I'm currently working on building out the entire code, then I'll add in de-bugging features, isolate, and work everything out as I go - but thanks for the input.